# API to determine whether the co-ordinate given is a road or a building?

Tags: android

We are creating an app on traffic monitoring and handling congestion. We want to know if there is a way we can find out about the place if it's a road or building using the Co ordinates

Answer (score 0):

You can use The Google Maps Geocoding API's [reverese geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) service.

### Example of Reverse Geocoding

The following query contains the latitude/longitude value for a location in Brooklyn:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```